# Progress bar is more then i can code today for some reason

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, progress-bar

I am having serious issues with a progress bar. I am building a custom backup utility, it allows users force their update now on a button click. When they click the button it calls a console application with the console window hidden runs the full backup process then completes. during the whole process there is no status or progress bar, due to the fact that after this install is done it will be transparent to the user....users cause issues we all know that. During the GUI interaction there needs to be something that tells the admin that it's doing something. here is my code:

```
private void forback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(MethodToGetInfo);
        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void MethodToGetInfo(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        Process info = new Process();
        info.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        info.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Rameses\\Program\\Day_Cloud_Backup.exe";
        info.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.Start();
    }

    void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("it's f***ing done");
    }
```

what the heck am I doing wrong. I click the button, the app runs... but the message box shows right away and the progress bar doesn't stop.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here.

For the Progress bar to stop, you need to tell it to stop in the RunWorkerCompleted callback (in your case, change the style).

For the thread to not return immediately, you need to block in the thread to wait until the Process you kicked off is completed.  One way to do this is to use the WaitForExit Process method:

```
...
info.Start();
info.WaitForExit();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx

This will make the thread wait until your process is done before calling the WorkerCompleted callback.

Comment: thank you. I didn't notice that I was missing that. apparently late night partying and morning coding does not work well.